# play with button radius LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-button

Hello everybody I was wondering if anybody could help me. I want to round the lightning-button in a LWC. I found something like this 'border-radius-circle' but it does not work.
Could anybody put an example? Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) you cannot change the style of standard component unless the CSS property is setted via custom properties.

Looking at the [buttons blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview) in Styling Hooks section you'll find the one for the border-radius: `--slds-c-button-radius-border`.
So if you want to change the default value you could give your button a CSS class, i.e. `circle`, then set the desider value to the custom property `--slds-c-button-radius-border`:

CSS

```css
:host .circle {
    --slds-c-button-radius-border: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```html
<lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="Button" class="circle"></lightning-button>
```